# Flutter build archives for iOS fails in stable

Tags: iphone, archive

I am using Flutter stable 1.22.5 for my app and its running perfect on iPhone 14.2. But I can't archive my build to release it on TestFlight.
I got errorParse Issue Group
ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: Module 'apple_sign_in' not found. Same error in master and beta. I have already tried to remove iOS folder and create it again, but that doesn't work. The following terminal commands have also been used:

1. Flutter clean
2. rm -Rf iOS/Pods
3. rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
4. rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
5. rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
6. pod cache clean —all
7. Flutter get packages
8. pod install and update.

My issue only appears at archive build for release on iPhone. How do I fix this?

**Podfile**

## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.3'

```
# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
          pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/https-gpl', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      else
          pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Solved it with upgrading iOS deployment target to 12.0. This can be closed.

Comment: go ahead and post your solution as an answer, then mark the answer completed.